# Is there a canonical Taylor expansion for operators in terms of $X$ and $P$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, phase-space, wigner-transform

Consider the algebra of operators acting on wavefunctions ($L^2(\mathbb{R})$) generated by $X$ and $P = -i\hbar (\partial/\partial x)$.  For some operator $A$ in this algebra, or possibly in a restricted class of nice operators, is there a canonical Taylor expansion in terms of $X$ and $P$?  In other words, is there a canonical way to write $A$ as an infinite (scaler-weighted) sum of finite products of $X$ and $P$,

$$A = a_0 I + a_{\mathrm{x}}X + a_{\mathrm{p}}P + a_{\mathrm{xx}}X^2 + a_{\mathrm{xp}}XP + a_{\mathrm{px}}PX  + a_{\mathrm{pp}}P^2 + \cdots$$

where the scalar weights $a_i$ can be computed with derivative-like commutators, e.g.,  $$a_{\mathrm{x}} = \frac{\partial A }{\partial X} := -i[A,P]$$

or something like that?

One possibility is to consider the Wigner transform $W[A]$ of $A$, take the normal Taylor expansion of $W[A]$ in terms of phase-space scalars $x$ and $p$, and then do the Weyl transform (i.e, inverse Wigner transform) on each term in the series.  That should probably converge (in which norm?) for at least some restricted set of well-behaved operators $A$.  But the Wigner transform is well-known to be just one choice of phase-space transform associated with a particular operator ordering; presumably this series would then change if a phase-space transform associated with a different operator ordering were used.  Would the series still sum to $A$ regardless?

Are Bopp operators relevant here?

And is there a nice way to do this without the Wigner transform?  In particular, is there something like [Taylor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem) that can be expressed purely in terms of commutators and a series?

---

EDIT: An $n$-th degree polynomial in operators $X$ and $P$ will correspond to an $n$-th degree polynomial in classical variables $x$ and $p$ for all choices of phase-space transform because the degree of a polynomial in $X$ and $P$ is not changed by re-ordering (i.e., commuting the operators around). (Both sides of $XP = PX + i\hbar$ are second degree.) Therefore, if the $n$-th degree Taylor approximation to an operator is defined with a phase-space transform, it is *independent* of the particular phase-space transform.  (This point was emphasized to me by Dan Ranard.)

Comment: This expansion is not unique, since for example you could write $XP = PX + [X, P] = PX + i$ (in units where $\hbar=1$). I think you could use this fact so you could write each term in the form $c_{m,n} X^m P^n$ for some $m,n$. In other words, you could use the commutator to get ride of terms like $X^p P^r X^q$ (where $p$, $q$, $r$ are all nonzero). I'm not sure if there is a general way to compute the $c_{m,n}$ though, other than formally treating $X$ and $P$ as scalars after ordering them in the standard form above, differentiating the series wrt $X,P$ $m,n$ times, and setting $X=P=0$.

Comment: Sure, expressing the series using terms only of the form $X^m P^n$ would, I think, essentially be a choice of operator ordering corresponding to some (non-Wigner) choice of phase-space representation.  I'm wondering if there's anything canonical (nice properties) besides the Wigner proposal I mentioned.  I don't understand the second part of your comment; it seems to assume you already have an expression for the series in terms of polynomials in $X$ and $P$.